# how to populate an array or any object from one view controller to another when we present the view using story board

Tags: iphone, objective-c, storyboard, presentmodalviewcontroller

I have implemented my iphone app using **story board**

In my app **i need to present a view from one view to another view not the pus**h,

I have created a screen in story board xib for the second view .

i ***`set up the connection for button in the first view to the second view with 'present`***' not pust.

Now *`i need to populate an array to the second view which was presented`*
i tried following ways but not work out

1:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(UIButton *)sender
{

    //Populate detail to BuyView mail page
    if ([segue.id

entifier isEqualToString:@"BuyView"])
        {
            BuyViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

            destViewController.itemDetailsArray = [_itemDetailsArray objectAtIndex:sender.tag] ;
        }

    }
```

2:

```
- (IBAction)buyItemClick:(UIButton *)sender
{
BuyViewController *destViewController = [[BuyViewController alloc] init];

    destViewController.itemDetailsArray = [_itemDetailsArray objectAtIndex:sender.tag] ;
}
```

Comment: What "following ways"? Also, "I have created a story board xib for the second view " makes no sense -- do you mean you created a scene in the storyboard for your second view controller?

Comment: Was a solution found?

Answer (score 0):

On top of what @rdelmar has stated you are passing an object of which may or may not be an array.

Which in turn would mean

```
destViewController.itemDetailsArray
```

Would be pointing to an object which may not be an array.

I think what you want to do is

```
 destViewController.itemDetailsArray = _itemDetailsArray;
```